# How to install package control to Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, packages, installation-package

How can I install package control to Sublime Text 3?

- As noted, it says this:

  > Open the Sublime Text 2 console by pressing Ctrl + `

But when I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, it just writes the below character:

```
This character:  `
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw an option named "install package control" in Preferences menu,

I have selected this and Sublime Text application have installed Package Control.

Thanks to idleberg to find me.